# Unnecessary horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, datatables, scrollbar

I'm trying to build an asp.net mvc view with a jquery datatable. My datatable contains only one filed (role name), and the delete/update/show buttons links.
the problem is that an unnecessary horizontal scroll bar is displayed :

[image]

How can i avoid this unnecessary scroll bar ?

Below is a snippet of my view :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header"> Roles management </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 ">
        <legend>Liste des rôles </legend>       
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table width="100" class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Designation role</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Name
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="b-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Role")'">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ajouter un role
                </button>
            </div>      
    </fieldset>
 </div>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think it is because of the padding, margin or something. You can debug using the "F12" key.

Comment: It would be handy if we can see the CSS you have.

Comment: Actually i'm using the sb-admin bootstrap theme

Comment: But it could be that you edited some kind of of thing in the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this css:

```
overflow-x:hidden
```

to the div that wraps the `fieldset`.

Comment: thanks man; it worked! but in the div that wrapp the datatable  :      <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x: hidden;">